# Ruby on Rails CSS files not found when deployed in heroku

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am using a themeforest by webster. I've added them to my ruby on rails app. It works perfectly fine in localhost. But when uploaded to heroku, the css files are not found. It wont load all the css files.

please refer to https://racepackdelivery.herokuapp.com/

```
`// in application.css
*= require css/plugins-css
*= require css/typography
*= require css/style
*= require css/responsive
*= require_tree .`
```

Comment: What do  you write in application.css ? please add code of application.css in question.

Comment: The styles you are importing in `application.css` are ot loading in production. Try running `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` locally to look for errors.

Comment: @naz, Please have a look my answer and try it.

Answer (score 0):

It can happen when `config.serve_static_files` is not set to true in your `production.rb` file. You can make it true and try deploying again.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Solution:**

I had the same problem in rails 4 so i fixed with adding

```
1. Add gem in production 'rails_12factor'    
2. bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

**2. Solution:**

To load assets in production environment:

[How to load assets in production rails](https://taimoorchangaizpucitian.wordpress.com/2015/11/08/rails-production-environment-assets-loading/)

Note: After following above link

```
rm -rf tmp/*
rm -rf public/assets/*
RAILS_ENV='production' rake assets:precompile
```

then restart your server

**3. Solution:**

Check that in /config/environments/production.rb you have these set to true

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

git add, git commit and push to heroku.

Comment: i dont think this is related. as i'm using rails 5.1.4 the latest version.. rails 5 no longer requires the rails_12factor...

Comment: @naz, You are correct. Rails 5 don't need this gem. but you can try other solutions.

Comment: same. added the configs to true in production.rb.. it still has error. unable to load files... but why is it working in localhost but not in heroku?? that really bugs me...

Comment: Where did you stored you css files ?

Comment: in app/assets/stylesheets/

Comment: Use bundle exec rake assets:precompile
then it will create some files then push it to heroku

Comment: i did that too. precompiled the js and css files.

Comment: i dont have any gitignore yet. just the pre coded gitignore